# Why, in my form's OnLoad, is my form blinking when I set background images?

Tags: c#, winforms

Why, in my form's OnLoad, is my form blinking when I set background images?

Comment: Please post what **properties** you have setted to the `Form`..

Comment: Jus Added backround image. and layout is Streach.

Answer (score 3):

It's because it is being redrawn. Redrawing first clears the background and then draws the image onto it. This causes the flickering.

You can activate double-buffering on the form to eliminate this problem:

```
this.DoubleBuffered = true;
```

Comment: The form is not yet visible when OnLoad runs, that doesn't happen until OnShown.  So nothing is getting redrawn.

Comment: Can you add some code in your post to show you set the image? (it's of course not redrawn in OnLoad, but it's a good place to set the doublebuffered property...).

Comment: You need to add it before the initialization process, not the Form_Load event. You can always set it as a property on the designer if I remember correctly.

Comment: This is not correct. The property only uses the `SetStyle` to enable double-buffering. In fact, the example here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.controlstyles.aspx shows `SetStyle` being used in the Page's Load event.

Answer (score 0):

Set DobleBuffered = true for the target form as 'user1693593' answered above. I spent more than 2 hours to fix this. Thanks to 'user1693593', I finally got rid of blinking issue. Honor 'user1693593' not me.

When the target form is double buffered, the target form will not be blinking when 'loaded,' which means called by targetForm.Show(Onwer).

Comment: Hi Brian, it's not clear the value your answer brings. The upvote might cover this case. Always good to appreciate people's replies thou